# what are the some useful resources to learn Raspberry pi?

Tags: pi-2

I am a newbie in IoT, but have a little bit knowledge of programming languages: python, nodejs etc. Can someone point me toward some useful resources to learn Raspberry pi 2?

Answer (score 2):

There are some free online courses developed by (or in conjunction with) the Raspberry Pi foundation. [You can find 9 courses here at the FutureLearn website](https://www.futurelearn.com/partners/raspberry-pi). In particular, as you have some programming experience, you may be interested in the course on [physical computing](https://www.futurelearn.com/courses/physical-computing-raspberry-pi-python).

This should get you started, but of course it's only a start. And everyone learns a bit differently, but I've always felt that "learning by doing" is vastly superior to most other methods. You'll learn far more by diving into these projects, making mistakes, and solving them than you will by reading about how others have solved a problem. That's not to say that you won't learn anything from others - you can and will learn masses of lessons from others, but only to say that you must invest your own time in solving problems to gain any mastery. In other words, I am suggesting this:

- Read/study or take an online course to learn what the Raspberry Pi is, and what it can do.
- Read/study about one or two projects that interest you.
- Begin designing and building building your own projects; start simple, then increase complexity.

You should come here and post questions once you've developed and tried your own solutions. If you ask questions that indicate you've not invested any time or effort in a solution, you may find that the most experienced users here are not that keen on helping. Finally, you could read the short piece here on ["How to Ask A Good Question"](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask); following this guidance will pay you dividends.